# Firebase on handler is always triggering

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I’m using the following script:

```
var conversation = firebase.database().ref('conversations');
conversation.on('value', (snapshot) => {
  const data = snapshot.val();
  document.getElementById('#btn').click();
});
```

However, the on is always triggering even if there is no new data on the database. I know this because the button is always being pressed.

Does anyone knows what I’m doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. An `on('value'` listener immediately fires with a snapshot of the current value at that path in the database, and will fire again if any data under that path changes. Firebase synchronizes the state of the (paths you observe in the) database, it does not just pass messages around about changes as they happen (as a message queue would do).

If you want to get only new data, you should have some indication of what "new" means. For more on this, I recommend checking out some of the previous questions on [only getting new data from Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D%5Bjavascript%5D+only+new).

Comment: The problem is that it is firing all the time. Even if there isn’t new data. The problem is not the fact that it gets the entire node, the problem is that it should fire only when new data is added. Isn’t it?

Comment: Listeners fire immediately with a snapshot of the current data.

Comment: Thanks, however, the firebase documentation says: "You can use the value event to read a static snapshot of the contents at a given path, as they existed at the time of the event. " Another thing, does 'child_added' fire every time or only when a child is added?

Comment: If you think the documentation is unclear, there's a link to leave feedback at the bottom of every page. The behavior is as I describe it here though. `child_added` also immediately fires for every existing child. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_child_events, which says about `child_added`: "This event is triggered once for each existing child and then again every time a new child is added to the specified path."

Comment: Thanks, Frank. As it says in the documentation, it should only fire when a new child is added and not all the time...

Comment: No it doesn't: "**This event is triggered once for each existing child**...". I know this is not what you want the API to do. You'll have to find another way to accomplish your use-case on top of this API, which is why I explained the most common option in my answer.